# Finding FastSearch server name

Tags: fast-search

I installed FastSearch for SP2010. While configuring it asked me for it's server name and default port, now I don't remember setting the server name while installing because I uninstalled and re-installed it .
How can I find the server name to use it in the configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

When you install Fast Search it creates a fastsearch folder on the drive.  if you have not deleted this folder you can get the information from the install.info file in this folder.